# Execute code as early as possible in iOS application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, linker, initialization

I'm trying to find a proper place to dynamically rebind symbols in my binary. So I want to ensure that rebind happens before I load any 3rd-party frameworks. What is the earliest point I can execute my code in iOS application?

As per Apple documentation for `+[NSObject load]`:

> The order of initialization is as follows:
>
> - All initializers in any framework you link to.
> - All +load methods in your image.
> - All C++ static initializers and C/C++ **attribute**(constructor)
>     functions  in your image.
> - All initializers in frameworks that link to you.

So, I think I should create a framework, and add my code to his initializer. But how to make sure that my framework initializer is called before other frameworks initializers? Which exact initializer I should use to make sure that it's executed first?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Jens I've updated my question

Comment: @BorisVerebsky did you ever figure out the solution to your problem?

Comment: @iOSAddicted unfortunately, the answer is no. I didn't spend too much time digging into it though. This question is still actual to me.

Comment: @BorisVerebsky I wanted to be able to print pre-main time without the need of the environmental variable (DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS).

the C++ attribute constructor is the last function to get called before the main. I can get +load method to get called before that